# Undetected Chromedriver gets detected on some site (vzu.us)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, cloudflare, undetected-chromedriver

I'm facing a cloudflare loop in vzu.us using undetected chromedriver. The code I ran:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://vzu.us')
```

After that, A turnstile captcha shows and I manually solve it (Just click on the checkbox). Then It reloads the same page asking the same captcha to solve again. This continues until I close browser. I've tried nowsecure.nl site which seems undetected chromedriver is able to bypass cloudflare in that case. I tried with 3 more sites where it's able to bypass. But this (vzu.us) site is stuck in redirect loop.

Comment: did you fixed this issue?

Comment: @ZARIR did you solve this?  If so, can you post the solution as your answer please?

Comment: I moved to [DrissionPage](https://pypi.org/project/DrissionPage/) module. It is far better than this. CloudFlare cant detect it normally. But the headless mode of it gets detected.